# Convert day-time column to integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I've looked everywhere for a solution to this issue but nothing seems to work.

I have a column in my dataframe `df_jan`

```
459984                   0
451375                   0
660585                   0
722735    78 days 00:00:00
448295                   0
                ...       
585781     4 days 00:00:00
612351    22 days 00:00:00
631985    16 days 00:00:00
462341                   0
450073                   0
Name: delta_sale, Length: 12978, dtype: object
```

I want to change it so that it is simply the integer value of days.

I've tried the following:

```
pd.to_datetime()
df_jan['delta_sale'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
.astype(int)
```

However, none of them have worked and I'm struggling to find any other questions that have the same issue. All I'm trying to achieve is this,

```
459984                   0
451375                   0
660585                   0
722735                  78
448295                   0
                ...       
585781                   4
612351                  22
631985                  16
462341                   0
450073                   0
Name: delta_sale, Length: 12978, dtype: int
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the output of `df_jan['delta_sale'].head(10).to_dict()`?

Comment: {459984: 0,
 451375: 0,
 660585: 0,
 722735: Timedelta('78 days 00:00:00'),
 448295: 0,
 447706: 0,
 451721: Timedelta('6 days 00:00:00'),
 451288: 0,
 643505: Timedelta('245 days 00:00:00'),
 449251: 0}

Comment: what is the output of: `df_jan['delta_sale'].dtype`?

Comment: can you try either: `df_jan['delta_sale'].dt.days` or `pd.to_timedelta(df_jan['delta_sale']).dt.days`?

Comment: pd.to_timedelta(df_jan['delta_sale']).dt.days works!!! Thank you! I've been stuck on this for ages

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.apply()` in combination with a short temporary function `lambda x: x.day`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.Timestamp.now(), pd.Timestamp.now()]})

df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
```

This yields (because today is the 16th)

> 0    16
> 1    16
> Name: date, dtype: int64